# Stata: Cumulative number of new observations

Tags: regex, stata

I would like to check if a value has appeared in some previous row of the same column.
At the end I would like to have a cumulative count of the number of distinct observations.

Is there any other solution than concenating all _n rows and using regular expressions? I'm getting there with concatenating the rows, **but given the limit of 244 characters for string variables (in Stata <13), this is sometimes not applicable**.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
gen tmp=x
replace tmp = tmp[_n-1]+ "," + tmp if _n > 1
gen cumu=0
replace cumu=1 if regexm(tmp[_n-1],x+"|"+x+",|"+","+x+",")==0
replace cumu= sum(cumu)
```

Example

```
        +-----+
        |  x  | 
        |-----|
     1. |  12 |
     2. |  32 |
     3. |  12 |
     4. |  43 |
     5. |  43 |
     6. |  3  |
     7. |  4  |
     8. |  3  |
     9. |  3  |
    10. |  3  |
        +-----+
```

becomes

```
        +-------------------------------+
        |  x  | tmp                     |
        |-----|--------------------------
     1. |  12 |  12                     |
     2. |  32 |  12,32                  |
     3. |  12 |  12,32,12               |
     4. |  43 |  3,32,12,43             |
     5. |  43 |  3,32,12,43,43          |
     6. |  3  |  3,32,12,43,43,3        |
     7. |  4  |  3,32,12,43,43,3,4      |
     8. |  3  |  3,32,12,43,43,3,4,3    |
     9. |  3  |  3,32,12,43,43,3,4,3,3  |
    10. |  3  |  3,32,12,43,43,3,4,3,3,3|
        +--------------------------------+
```

and finally

```
        +-----------+
        |  x  | cumu|
        |-----|------
     1. |  12 |  1  |
     2. |  32 |  2  |
     3. |  12 |  2  |
     4. |  43 |  3  |
     5. |  43 |  3  |
     6. |  3  |  4  |
     7. |  4  |  5  |
     8. |  3  |  5  |
     9. |  3  |  5  |
    10. |  3  |  5  |
        +-----------+
```

Any ideas how to avoid the 'middle step' (for me that gets very important when having strings in `x` instead of numbers).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are great, but here as often elsewhere simple calculations suffice. With your sample data

```
. input x 

             x
  1.         12 
  2.         32 
  3.         12 
  4.         43 
  5.         43 
  6.         3  
  7.         4  
  8.         3  
  9.         3  
 10.         3  
 11. end 


end of do-file
```

you can identify first occurrences of each distinct value:

```
. gen long order = _n

. bysort x (order) : gen first = _n == 1

. sort order

. l

     +--------------------+
     |  x   order   first |
     |--------------------|
  1. | 12       1       1 |
  2. | 32       2       1 |
  3. | 12       3       0 |
  4. | 43       4       1 |
  5. | 43       5       0 |
     |--------------------|
  6. |  3       6       1 |
  7. |  4       7       1 |
  8. |  3       8       0 |
  9. |  3       9       0 |
 10. |  3      10       0 |
     +--------------------+
```

The number of distinct values seen so far is then just a cumulative sum of `first` using `sum()`. This works with string variables too. In fact this problem is one of several discussed within

http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042

which is accessible to all as a .pdf. `search distinct` would have pointed you to this article.

Becoming fluent with what you can do with `by:`, `sort`, `_n` and `_N` is an important skill in Stata. See also

http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004

for another article accessible to all.

Comment: Brilliant Nick! I had this feeling that there must be 'simple' solution for this! Thanks!